# Expected value of $|X - Y|$

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Let $X \sim U(0, 1)$ and $Y \sim U(0, 2)$ be independent random variables. What's the expected value of $|X - Y|$? I found $f_{X}(x) = 1$ and $f_{Y} = \frac{1}{2}$ so that $f_{XY}(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}$ and

$$\mathbb{E}[|x - y|] = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2} \frac{|x - y|}{2} \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx},$$

but how can I compute this quantity? It looks tricky. I know the trick where you split the integral in the one-dimensional case, but I'm having trouble getting it in the two-dimensional case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^2 \frac{|x-y|}{2} \, dy \, dx = \int_{x=0}^1 \left( \int_{y=0}^x \frac{x-y}{2} \, dy + \int_{y=x}^2 \frac{y-x}{2} \, dy \right) \, dx.$$

Comment: Thanks... not sure why I couldn't think of this :)

Comment: [The answer is $\frac23$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%28+%28int_0%5Ex+%28x-y%29%2F2+dy+%29+%2B+%28int_x%5E2+%28y-x%29%2F2+dy%29+%29+dx)