# Why can't I use linearity of conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813873/expected-value-of-x-y) on which asks:

> Let ∼(0,1)  and ∼(0,2)  be independent random variables.
> What's the expected value of |−| ?

I understand the provided solution, but I was wondering why this method below, which uses linearity of conditional expectation, doesn't work:
\begin{align}
E[|X-Y|]&=E[X-Y|X>Y]\\
&=\int_0^2E[X-Y|X>Y,Y=y]f(y)dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2E[X-Y|X>Y,Y=y]dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2(E[X|X>Y,Y=y]-E[Y|X>Y,Y=y])dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\left(\frac{2+y}{2}-y\right)dy\\
&=1/2.
\end{align}
Which differs from the correct answer, 1/3.

Comment: The second equality is false.

Comment: Why? Doesn't the second line follow from the law of total expectation?

Comment: If $f(y)$ is the pdf of $Y$, then no, it doesn't follow from the law of total expectation.  (If it's the appropriate pdf to make the second equality true, then the third is false, as the appropriate pdf isn't $f(y) = 1/2$)

Comment: Yes, $f_Y(y)$ is the PDF of $y$. Can you please help me understand why it doesn't follow from the law of total expectation? Does LOTE not apply to integrals?

Comment: Honestly, you probably ought to revert this question to the one that was answered already and submit a new question.  Then someone can explain the error.  If nothing else, you can use my comments to help focus your next question.

Comment: Done. Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 3):

Your first line is incorrect, using the law of total expectation it should read
$$E[|X-Y|] = E[X-Y|X > Y]P(X > Y) + E[Y-X|Y > X]P(Y > X).$$

Comment: Yes, but by symmetry, $P(X>Y)=1/2$ and $E[X-Y | X>Y] = E[Y-X | Y>X].$, so it simplifies to $E[|X-Y|] = E[X-Y | X>Y]$

Comment: You said $Y \sim Unif(0,2)$ and $X\sim Unif(0,1)$, so $P(Y > X)> 1/2.$